# AWS Managed Updates life cycle hooks

Tags: amazon-web-services

In our cloud formation template parameters we have the following set to enable AWS Managed Updates:

```
    "ManagedActionsEnabled": {
      "Description": "",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "true"
    },
    "PreferredStartTime": {
      "Description": "",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "Sat:06:00"
    },
    "ServiceRoleForManagedUpdates": {
      "Description": "Managed Updates Service Role",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "AWSServiceRoleForElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdates"
    },
```

Is there a life cycle hook for Managed Updates that can be targeted to provide an event notification just before upgrading an environment?

We need to hit our application's REST api to do a backup just before the AWS managed update is performed.

Comment: What is the template?

Comment: updated to add the cfn properties.